# Thymeleaf webflux AND mvc engine in parallel

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I have read that `spring-boot-starter-web` can coexist to `spring-boot-starter-webflux` in parallel.

**So i am curious if thymeleaf can have coexisting templating engines, one for mvc, one for webflux?**

I did some greenfield projects testing it, but it seemed that this is not intended to work.

For my understanding of this spring boot autoconfig class it depends on the type of web (mvc or weblux) application which engine will be used:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java

Comment: No. You can only have 1 technology for the server (either reactive or not). You can use reactive types in the web part but that is only partially reactive (it will adapt to the async servlet api nothing more). However you could try an tweak everything manuallly but auto-config is for one of the other not both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid of that. But nevertheless! I will try to move out the `spring-boot-starter-web` and see what happens.